# How to bold numbers within a cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to automatically bold numbers within a cell.

example if in a cell it says:

$1,000 was spent on this campaign over the last 30 days.

I would like the cell to look like this:
**$1,000**  was spent on this campaign over the last **30** days.

Is there a script I can use?

Comment: You want any numbers bold?

Comment: You could do it with RichText

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use `RichTextValueBuilder` to bold text.

I have a simple spreadsheet as shown.

[image]

Code.gs

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let text = sheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
    // get all numbers
    let numbers = text.match(/\$*\d{1,},*\d*/g);
    let bold = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).build();
    let richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue();
    richText = richText.setText(text);
    numbers.forEach( number => {
        let start = text.indexOf(number);
        let end = start+number.length;
        let pad = "x";
        // String.replace required so you don't indexOf() a similar number
        text = text.replace(number,pad.repeat(number.length));
        richText = richText.setTextStyle(start,end,bold);
      }
    );
    sheet.getRange("B2").setRichTextValue(richText.build());
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

References:

- [String.match()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)
- [Regexr](https://regexr.com/)
- [SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newTextStyle())
- [SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextBuilder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder)
- [Range.setRichTextValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setRichTextValue(RichTextValue))

List item